# Linux file and string search

Tags: linux, search

I am a n00b to Linux. I am trying to understand the source code of a large C++ project
that includes a bunch of other headers and such.

In one of the main files, I see a bunch of function calls, but I don't see the defintion in the file itself, so its obviously getting included from somewhere else.

I am looking for a way to search for the file or the place where the function is actually defined. Is there a way to do that? Please help. I am using Linux as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with a command like

```
find . -name '*.[ch]*' | xargs grep some_search_term
```

For more advanced searching, you should consider looking into [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) or [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: no need for `xargs` here. You can use the `-exec` option of find. `find . -name '*.[ch]*' -exec grep some_search_term {} \;`

Comment: Sure, if you prefer more complicated syntax and slower runtime.

Answer (score 1):

look into [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) for searching strings within headers/text files, etc.